# error in starting services using Ambari

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, emc

I am using hdp 2.5.3, with isilon storage as DataNode, Ambari shows below error whenever i want to start yarn or hive

```
self.util.run_command(self.main_resource.resource.target, 'SETPERMISSION', method='PUT', permission=self.mode, assertable_result=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/providers/hdfs_resource.py", line 192, in run_command
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'curl -sS -L -w '%{http_code}' -X PUT 'http://zonehdfs.isi.mcci.local:8082/webhdfs/v1/ats/done?op=SETPERMISSION&user.name=hdfs&permission=755'' returned status_code=403. 
{
  "RemoteException": {
    "exception": "AccessControlException", 
    "javaClassName": "org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException", 
    "message": "Permission denied: user=hdfs, access=WRITE, path=\"/ats/done\""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear. The User hdfs wants for Write in the Folder `/ats/done` and is not allowed to. Give him the write-permissions and it should work.

Comment: the path is on Isilon, hdfs user id is 501, and the owner of the path is 501.

Comment: But has the owner write permissions?

Comment: Looks like the scripe wants to Change the permission and is not allowed to `done?op=SETPERMISSION&user.name=hdfs&permission=755`